# How can we call Php functions based on the Java script If-else condition?

Tags: php, javascript

How can we call Php functions with in the JavaScript If-else condition.

For Example,

```
 if (top == self) {

  // not in any kind of frame

} else {

// in a frame

// calling php function

}
</script>
```

Here, PHP exit() function calling for both if and else conditions. I need to call that function for only in else part.

Please advise me.

Thanks.
Prabhu

Comment: This is fundamentally not possible because PHP runs on the server; JavaScript runs on the user's browser long after PHP is done running.

Comment: Please learn the difference between server-side and client-side languages.

Comment: What kind of function do you want to call? There is probably a JavaScript equivalent for what you want to do, or you can make an Ajax call.

Comment: You could issue an AJAX request to the desired PHP function in your else `$.get("exit.php")` - But that will accomplish little for your running Javascript code. That's intended to fetch new data, not for mixing PHP and JS control flow.

Comment: actually, i planned to call wordpress hook function, also that hook function should call for iframe window only

Answer (score 5):

Technically not possible. However you can make an AJAX call to a PHP page and get the values returned by it.

PHP (test.php):

```
<?php
$x = 10;
$y = 20;
$val = $y / $x;

echo $val;
?>
```

Javascript ([jQuery](http://jquery.com/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({url: 'test.php',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
         //takes the value returned by test.php and
         //puts it directly into the element with 
         //id = someElement
         $('#someElement').html(data);
      }
});
```

As far as calling `exit();` and making the page that holds the JavaScript stop processing, you just can't unless you control the logic on that same page in PHP and call `exit();` from there.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to mix javascript with php.

If you want to stop the page from loading you could also redirect the page to an other (php) page where you simply put exit();

If this javascript is in a function just  use : return; or return false;